# How can I fix the damage in PDF files requested using MS2XML.XMLHTTP?

Tags: pdf, download, httprequest, buffer, visual-foxpro

Friends, this is my first question here... I've been facing some problems when downloading a PDF buffer using MS2XML.XMLHTTP. I've been using Genexus to do so but I also tried right in pure Visual Fox Pro. The problem is that when I send the ResponseText to a string variable, some characters are replaced by question marks, the sam happens when I send the ResponseText to a pdf or txt file. The object created in MS2XML.XMLHTTP.6.0 does not allow using the ResponseBody property. Any thoughts on how could I solve it using MS2XML.XMLHTTP? Thanks.

```
oHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")  
oHTTP.Open("GET", 'https://homologacao.plugboleto.com.br/api/v1/boletos/impressa  /lote/NIKLfYBWz',.F.)
oHTTP.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/pdf")
oHTTP.Send()
? oHTTP.responseText
```

I've received someething like the following (full of question marks):

%PDF-1.4 %??2 0 obj <</ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Subtype/Image/Height 38/Filter/DCTDecode/Type/XObject/Width 149/BitsPerComponent 8/Length 2619>>stream ???JFIF  H H  ??C     !"$"$??C?? & ?" ??             ???   } !1AQa"q2???#B??R?$3br?    %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz????????????????????????????????????????????????????          ???  w !1AQaq"2?B????#3R??$4?&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz???????????????????????????????????????????????????  ? ?h???8OO????a&??G?3? ?*p1???|b?o?? ??x?_???%??E?en9??T???T>.????JG??rx??????????h?w????????:?!?????????jlm?Tn???????*u??? ??Ey?PA?? (?? (?? (?? (??>B???;.??3?e??J??~?F??? y,s??i???#?m=kw???? ?[?K#????vR@G??^$?????k?[??BSu??#???M??????? _??Z?Fo??????/??*x?¾ mn??{)???80??s]W?x? ??+??k??=????????8 ?|D?c?j???h???$?8???:c??(???M/?Ze??;O?[?J????? '?~/j~!???n?urm???1^ITl;?3?%[?b??~?&<=u?Y\x??W6?¬$2?q?`1?;??qc??_??qk>?&?v?????,??F?{??x???s??????{?k????r8.?`?<P?|,????q?]I?]?e???p;??/?W?x??)???A?????&)??dc,?d7?J?s??m?>???????!??9Va?? c???Zv??x+?b?wd??f?8a????????,6????????x?? ?-????<9F???????[~$?{??o???X??????y?ZgQ?@8??ox;? ???|??mZ?? I~a?k ~P ?? j??? '?c??4?F??l??$?8???(?'?"?.?????,????9V?????d???????UU)??? ???o?&???4?7?Z?? g???y?
W[?????d?Q$?@??^mZ???B Z(??QE ?Q@Q@Q@Q@Q@??endstream endobj 6 0 obj <</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 846>>stream x??V???+?q??z???'U./h???{???d?U??xf??PQ?O???unA??*?x1?0 `50]@?\?T?y?B?s?9B? ?   2|????C???2t????k?U??]??]{? ?????s?AH??????h?"w????? f?????i??? ??>?9?8?#??"??G?$???<??0???S?2??sn?n??^?5?\FN?o1?4?~4~??Qe=&?T[???????Z??x??????k?????0z'#?;?'a?`?a?f~?q?~8ZH~?m???????Mm?p?@hh{????W7??????
?8?Olk'?A|?[???P?5?????uGxRr#?pw<$y?n?*?kD ???0??ih??9?5v??0?_}iG?Dq?8??_U??5a?????k????d???M??2???C*(??;t2uA]z ??6A??*o?t?}d????[?<;??R?iO8n??f???40???S?aV*X????Y?p2N?eq]N?VeE?>??/V0?]MV?&???.aZ-???z2???????????8o??3?S????????gf??B?'6??]?J endstream endobj 8 0 obj<</Contents 6 0 R/Type/Page/Resources<</ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]/Font<</F1 3 0 R/F2 4 0 R>>/XObject<</Xf1 1 0 R/Xf2 5 0 R/img0 2 0 R>>>>/Parent 7 0 R/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]>>endobj 3 0 obj<</Subtype/Type1/Type/Font/BaseFont/Helvetica-Bold/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding>>endobj 4 0 obj<</Subtype/Type1/Type/Font/BaseFont/Helvetica/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding>>endobj 5 0 obj <</Subtype/Form/Filter/FlateDecode/Type/XObject/Matrix [1 0 0 1 0 0]/FormType 1/Resources<</ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]>>/BBox[0 0 292.41 39]/Length 474>>stream x?m??e1C?@???1Ly}??Ua??>????r?R?????r?7gr??`a???\??PTj??p???s????~m"???:K??T???1????Gw({c????   !???p?rB g M?QG*?PC ?o??v?????'n[!n2??}*?g}r?G??J?R"aI?S??q   ???d;??-??m?????y?lCp??[B(=?L??G`[]2??)???
?8???9L????]y)?B??t<??E??????I????????@1?]$?    ??h??6?Q[A)?*8????<???????z??8c??????s??R????%6? endstream endobj 1 0 obj <</Subtype/Form/Filter/FlateDecode/Type/XObject/Matrix [1 0 0 1 0 0]/FormType 1/Resources<</ProcSet[/PDF/Text]/ExtGState 9 0 R/Font 10 0 R>>/Length 1818/BBox[0 0 595.28 419.53]>>stream x???Ko???t??V|???4-$n??{Pm%]6????P????:?$E?6i ?4??????d??m.U?7L????E??"???e?^r??*c?*???????S#'?????????X?bz?k.J?3!?)??{?V ??'VS1?????8??L???? fU"&Fx?v?Q?9G??EL]?iLIN}?C?i~??4???J<??P?4Ec??F??P%c=!
?=?!U??P?T?b]???k>+¹&?5?9A5ai?"???G????H???J??J?#N??@?3dP??#O=A6%??&dO?eU&5;?Q?@M?'??.??8????P???z!
'??j??O?8??7?
?f????????u???^???:N#?q?Y?xN6Kjv B??Z?????<??   Dx^?J??;A1?3s /?S?k?8??'?9?n??.w?s`????g????? M<0????????<?,p???xG!pv?v?`?O?`?,?!pv?v?P?`?l?O??3?M)[????????x??D?h????Z??&i)??,????k???k????j*???-?`@?'?x9D)]?J:?=?G??1r? ???!???X?I???|n?q}?=?6?:`ðl??????_T??[??_?AC???YI??????+??]??}f}S?P<{??EY??*@??q?pah???,Pj?????v~??a?c???{R*?7????? ?E~?mv??v?6??t ??    ??Y?????&???F?7P'?e?????R&??(?#????????)?2???P??j?.I??s4?|???s???$z????????E?P??x?{??tU?????????|??b?'?jH????f6 .?g? ?"?????iVR";;?P?'????F?????*??^?b?Nu6rO6? ?Xn[~>t???x2????n?[?D^????6C4O??vx??p?#???$?ru??Yj??55,?Z???u?&?yy????%????+????aMk?3 ???v?1M\A&?q???? '?Sf?,??ce)?   ??x?????P?#?Ea&y????/n??~8j???????Co????????????%??  ????????5C???(?<??}???OA???a$?)J?`?!vd????T????D{,?}^?e?]]@?'#T?v??J??;??4?G?e???&b?Bl???K????.?t=s?i?;6.>   ?????:?H??Z}:.V? ??) endstream endobj 9 0 obj<</R7 11 0 R/R9 12 0 R>>endobj 10 0 obj<</R8 13 0 R>>endobj 11 0 obj<</TK true/Type/ExtGState/BM/Normal/OPM 1>>endobj 12 0 obj<</Type/ExtGState/SA true>>endobj 13 0 obj<</Subtype/Type1/Type/Font/BaseFont/Helvetica/Encoding 14 0 R>>endobj 14 0 obj<</Type/Encoding/Differences[225/aacute/acircumflex/atilde 231/ccedilla 233/eacute/ecircumflex 243/oacute 245/otilde 250/uacute]>>endobj 7 0 obj<</Kids[8 0 R]/Type/Pages/Count 1>>endobj 15 0 obj<</Type/Catalog/Pages 7 0 R>>endobj 16 0 obj<<>>endobj xref 0 17 0000000000 65535 f  0000004765 00000 n  0000000015 00000 n  0000003908 00000 n  0000004000 00000 n  0000004087 00000 n  0000002787 00000 n  0000007190 00000 n  0000003700 00000 n  0000006794 00000 n  0000006833 00000 n  0000006863 00000 n  0000006922 00000 n  0000006965 00000 n  0000007044 00000 n  0000007240 00000 n  0000007285 00000 n  trailer<</Info 16 0 R/ID []/Root 15 0 R/Size 17>>startxref 7305 %%EOF

Comment: A PDF is a binary file, not a text file. Save and open using say ShellExecute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a PDF is a binary file and not a text file, it is quite normal you would see ? and all sorts of other non-printable characters. Instead save it to a file on disk and open with something like ShellExecute. ie:

```
oHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")  
oHTTP.Open("GET", 'https://homologacao.plugboleto.com.br/api/v1/boletos/impressa  /lote/NIKLfYBWz',.F.)
oHTTP.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/pdf")
oHTTP.Send()

Local lcFileName
lcFileName = Forcepath(Sys(2015)+'.pdf', Sys(2023))
Strtofile(oHttp.responseText, m.lcFileName)

Declare Long ShellExecute In "shell32.dll" ;
    long HWnd, String lpszOp, ;
    string lpszFile, String lpszParams, ;
    string lpszDir, Long nShowCmd

ShellExecute(_vfp.HWnd,'',m.lcFileName,'','',1)
```

EDIT: It was not a job MSXML2.XmlHttp. You simply download the file as a PDF and open it:

```
Local lcFileName, lcRemote
lcRemote = 'https://homologacao.plugboleto.com.br/api/v1/boletos/impressao/lote/NIKLfYBWz'

lcFileName = Forcepath(Sys(2015)+'.pdf', Sys(2023))

If (getFileFromURL(m.lcRemote, m.lcFileName) = 0)
    Declare Long ShellExecute In "shell32.dll" ;
        long HWnd, String lpszOp, ;
        string lpszFile, String lpszParams, ;
        string lpszDir, Long nShowCmd

    ShellExecute(_vfp.HWnd,'',m.lcFileName,'','',1) 
Endif

Procedure getFileFromURL
    Lparameters tcRemoteFile,tcLocalFile
    Declare Integer URLDownloadToFile In urlmon.Dll;
        INTEGER pCaller, String szURL, String szFileName,;
        INTEGER dwReserved, Integer lpfnCB
    Return URLDownloadToFile(0, m.tcRemoteFile, m.tcLocalFile, 0, 0)
endproc
```

Comment: @ Cetin Thanks for answering... It's been impossible to run that ShellExecute, it returns "OLE error code 0x80020006: Unknown name"... Anyway I used a Genexus function "Shell' which I think does the same thing and it still doesn't work, the file is still corrupted. Any idea?

Comment: @viniciusmattos, it is something at your end. Code works for me, provided that service really returns some PDF file. Yours is not testable because the link is faulty.

Comment: Here is the right link:  (https://homologacao.plugboleto.com.br/api/v1/boletos/impressao/lote/NIKLfYBWz) Do you think you could make a test on this link?   Thanks a lot!

Comment: @viniciusmattos, now that makes sense. You were pointing us in a wrong direction from the start with your MSXML2 code. It is not a job of MSXML but simply a download file from a URL. See the edited sample.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had no idea MSXML wasn`t the right option. Your code worked perfectly, problem solved. Thanks again!